# How do I extend dimension to variables in xarray's dataset? [python]

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I tried to extend the'isobaric' dimension to variables in the data.
Adding isobaric to the coordinates worked.
But, i can't expand dimension('isobaric') of the data variables.

Code is...

'''

```
NC = xr.open_dataset(ncfile)

pres_list = ['1000','975','950','925','900','875','850','800','750','700','650','600','550','500','450','400','350','300','250','200','150','100','70','50'];
p_list = np.array(pres_list, dtype = np.float64)

print(type(p_list))
NC = NC.metpy.parse_cf().squeeze()
NC = NC.assign_coords(isobaric = p_list)
print(NC)
```

'''

And this is result

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (isobaric: 24, x: 602, y: 781)
Coordinates:

- y                  (y) float64 0.0 1.5e+03 3e+03 ... 1.168e+06 1.17e+06
- x                  (x) float64 0.0 1.5e+03 3e+03 ... 9e+05 9.015e+05
  latitude           (y, x) float64 32.26 32.26 32.26 ... 42.94 42.94 42.93
  longitude          (y, x) float64 121.8 121.9 121.9 ... 132.5 132.5 132.5
  time               datetime64[ns] 2019-04-04
  metpy_crs          object Projection: latitude_longitude
- isobaric           (isobaric) float64 1e+03 975.0 950.0 ... 100.0 70.0 50.0
  Data variables:
  DZDT_1000mb        (y, x) float32 -0.008309841 0.0047516823 ... nan nan
  DZDT_975mb         (y, x) float32 -0.03171444 -0.01633358 ... nan nan
  DZDT_950mb         (y, x) float32 -0.008769512 -0.013530254 ... nan nan
  '''

There is no 'isobaric'coordinates in the initial data, so I added a value.
How can i expand the data variables dimension??
I want like this.(ex) DZDT_1000mb  (isobaric, y, x) blah blah~~)

plz help me!!!

Comment: Hi, have you tried `NC.expand_dims('isobaric')`?

Comment: I tried that way. However, i fixed this problem by applying 'TMP = xr.concat([tmp1,tmp2],'isobaric')' to each variable. 
I'll use your method next time. thank you!